# Web app open Excel file to modify then save, not working

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, blazor

In a Blazor with .NET 7 app, I have this code that modifies an Excel file and then saves it:

```
 if (matchNo >= 3)
 {
     range = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 8];
     range.Value2 = User.Identity.Name;
     xlWorkBook.Save();
     xlApp.Quit();
     Success = true;
     Message = "Record registered for you.";
     return;
 }
```

I can verify in debug that `User.Identity.Name` has a value and `i` is 8 with my sample data.

When the app reaches save, I get a dialog that says replace the existing Excel file and I choose "yes", then save is complete.

But when I go to `bin\debug\net7` or the project's `wwwroot` and open the Excel files, nothing is changed and the name of the user is not written in cell [8, 8].

I know this app may not work in the web, when I deploy it, since the save dialog box is not present there. But how to correct this app so that the file is modified?

And if there is a way to make it work in a web app so that the file saves without prompting? (I don't know why it is readonly when app runs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file was opened as readonly after flipping the flag to false the site is working correctly and without any prompt.

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(targetFilePath
 , 0, false /* < this flag */, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, false, 1, 0);
```